# Android NDK 11 NativeActivity debugging error in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, android-sdk-tools, eclipse-adt

I have been using Android NDK r10e along with eclipse ADT tools to debug and AndroidNative activity.

I have been using GCC as the compiler.

I recently update to NDK r11c. I also changed the compiler to clang in Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang
```

I did a clean and rebuild all, and then launched the debug configuration for eclipse. The build and install went well, but after the app launches and the debugger tries to connect I get the following error....

```
Error with command: C:\android-ndk-r11c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb --version
Cannot run program "C:\android-ndk-r11c\toolchains\arm-linux-androideabi-4.9\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\arm-linux-androideabi-gdb": Launching failed
```

Comment: How did you actually change the compiler? arm-linux-androideabi-4.9 in your log indicates you're using the GCC 4.9 toolchain still.

Comment: I changed it in Application.mk NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := clang

Comment: Where and how are you launching gdb? Also, while you can debug something built by clang with gdb, it would be more in-model to use lldb.

Comment: I am launching by hitting the debug application I icon in eclipse. GDB is the bundled debugger with android. I don't know if another debugger would work across ADB.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know what's going on behind the debug button, but you can definitely use lldb to debug on android. Sorry I can't help!